# Calcular/Multiplicar/Somar sem "R$"

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como posso realizar a soma mas eliminando ou desconsiderando o "R$", transformando em numero.

Os valores em R$ são gerados automaticamente pelo sistema.

Segue o código:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function (){
  document.querySelector('div.de').id = 'de';
  document.querySelector('div.por').id = 'por';
  document.querySelector('div.economize').id = 'economize';
  var Div = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(Div) ;
  Div.id = 'resultado';
  var Campo1 = document.getElementById("de")  .innerHTML  ;
  var Campo2 = document.getElementById("por")  .innerHTML  ;
  var Campo3 = document.getElementById("economize")  .innerHTML  ;
  var subtracao = eval(parseInt(Campo3) / parseInt(Campo1) * 100);
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML  = subtracao.toFixed(1)+"%"  ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="de"> R$ 266,00  </div>
<div class="por"> R$ 145,36</div>
<div class="economize"> R$  120,64</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: <div class="de"> R$ 266,00 </div>
<div class="por"> R$ 145,36</div>
<div class="economize"> R$  120,64</div>

Comment: Pode tirar aquele `eval`, é desnecessário e só vai tornar o código lento. Quando vir um `eval` em js por aí, 99% de chance de ser desnecessário! :)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, abraços!

Comment: Só alguns detalhes, vc ta fazendo `parseInt` (use `parseFloat`), pois, vai remover os centavos. Se o número tiver separador de milhar `"."` remova-os antes de fazer o paseFloat. `.innerHTML.replace('R$', '').replace('.','').replace(',','.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o replace, desta forma:

```
var Campo1 = document.getElementById("de").innerHTML.replace('R$', '').replace(',','.');
var Campo2 = document.getElementById("por").innerHTML.replace('R$', '').replace(',','.');
var Campo3 = document.getElementById("economize").innerHTML.replace('R$', '').replace(',','.');
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Edgar,

Comment: Se isso resolver não esqueça de marcar como resposta :) @lucasinverso

Comment: @lucasinverso E se votar, se você achar que é uma boa resposta